# Median block size calculation

Tags: monerod, median-blocksize, blocksize

**What's the easiest way to calculate the median size of the last 100 blocks programmatically?**

I have tried using monerod and the `print_block` and `print_bc` commands but neither shows the block size directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a **recent enough daemon**, you can run the `bc_dyn_stats 100` command, which will include the median block size over the last 100 blocks, among other things.

If you have a recent, but not so recent daemon, you can try the getinfo RPC call, which includes the current block size limit, which is twice the last 100 blocks median:

`curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/getinfo -d '{}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers but doesn't seem to work for me. I'm running 0.10.1.0: `bc_dyn_stats` is unknown and the curl thingy doesn't seem to contain the block size limit (it's got: alt_blocks_count, cumulative_difficulty, difficulty, grey_peerlist_size, height, incoming_connections_count, outgoing_connections_count, status, target, target_height, testnet, top_block_hash, tx_count, tx_pool_size, white_peerlist_size)

Comment: I added emphasis on "recent enough daemon". Recent enough should be three days ago for bc_dyn_stats, and a week before that for the getinfo field.

Comment: Oh - *that* recent :-) I'll patiently wait for the next release then. Thanks.